# Apple Dock like (Magnify items near mouse) control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, magnification

Does anyone know of any WPF controls that act like the Apple Dock (something like [this](http://jrgraphix.net/research/flash-dock-mx-2004.php)). If not how would you go about creating one? A horizontal listbox of images is simple but I can't seem to recreate the smooth magnification of the images based on where the mouse is. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert, but sounds like you'd do an animation on a ScaleTransform on the LayoutTransform of the items?

mouse enter would start animation to increase the scale, exit the reverse?